# Create a counter if max datetime for a particular row if fall in min - max datetime for rest of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my input Dataframe.
Dataframe:

```
# intialise data of lists.
df = {'eqmt_id':[1, 1,1,2,2],
        'brand_no':['BH40 122', 'BH40 200', 'BH40 541', 'BH40 619', 'BH40 649'],
       'ndt':['2021-03-28 05:10:00', '2021-04-25 20:31:00','2020-09-13 11:33:00', '2020-11-08 22:53:00','2020-12-02 04:46:00'],
       'min':['2021-03-28 05:30:00','2021-04-25 21:00:00','2020-09-13 12:00:00','2020-11-08 23:00:00','2020-11-17 05:00:00'],
       'max':['2021-04-06 08:00:00','2021-05-03 18:30:00','2020-09-23 12:30:00','2020-11-18 10:30:00','2020-12-09 18:00:00']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
#to date time
df['ndt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ndt'])
df['min'] = pd.to_datetime(df['min'])
df['max'] = pd.to_datetime(df['max'])
# Print the output.
df
```

Here I want to create a counter so that I will get to know in which row there is overlapping. So the process is, we will have to iterate through each of rows and compare with rest.

Suppose the first row (brand : BH40 122), Here we have to take max and then we have to compare it with rest all rows of dataframe, if the max of BH40 122 fall in any of the row i.e, other brand_no, then counter = counter + 1. And again 2nd row will run and check for rest of rows in dataframe and then update the counter.

| eqmt_id | brand_no | ndt | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BH40 122 | 2021-03-28 05:10:00 | 2021-03-28 05:30:00 | 2021-04-06 08:00:00 |
| 1 | BH40 200 | 2021-04-25 20:31:00 | 2021-04-25 21:00:00 | 2021-05-03 18:30:00 |
| 1 | BH40 541 | 2020-09-13 11:33:00 | 2020-09-13 12:00:00 | 2020-09-23 12:30:00 |
| 2 | BH40 619 | 2020-11-08 22:53:00 | 2020-11-08 23:00:00 | 2020-11-18 10:30:00 |
| 2 | BH40 649 | 2020-12-02 04:46:00 | 2020-11-17 05:00:00 | 2020-12-09 18:00:00 |

This is my end outcome

| eqmt_id | brand_no | ndt | min | max | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BH40 122 | 2021-03-28 05:10:00 | 2021-03-28 05:30:00 | 2021-04-06 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | BH40 200 | 2021-04-25 20:31:00 | 2021-04-25 21:00:00 | 2021-05-03 18:30:00 | 0 |
| 1 | BH40 541 | 2020-09-13 11:33:00 | 2020-09-13 12:00:00 | 2020-09-23 12:30:00 | 0 |
| 2 | BH40 619 | 2020-11-08 22:53:00 | 2020-11-08 23:00:00 | 2020-11-18 10:30:00 | 1 |
| 2 | BH40 649 | 2020-12-02 04:46:00 | 2020-11-17 05:00:00 | 2020-12-09 18:00:00 | 0 |

As we can see, if we iterate the BH40 619 (4th row) with rest, we will find that the max of BH40 619 (4th row) fall in the min and max of BH40 649 (last row), so counter = 1. My dataset is very last there can be multiple case were we will see counter and go upto 4-5.

I was trying but didn't get it how to finish :(

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    counter = 0
    max_date = row['max']
    brand_no = row['brand_no']
    
    #skipping the iterative row (above one)
    ndf = df[df['brand_no'] != brand_no]
    
    #Iterating for rest
    for index1, row1 in ndf.iterrows():
        if(max_date > row1['min'] and max_date< row1['max']):
            row['counter'] = counter+1
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a dataframe by date, by checking whether a datetime object is between two columns of datetime objects: `df[(df['min'] <= date) & (df['max'] >= date)]`. In your case it will always return minimally 1 row, which is the row whose `max` value your're processing. So we have to subtract 1 from the length of the filtered dataframe when putting this in `df.apply`:

```
df['counter'] = df['max'].apply(lambda x: len(df[(df['min'] <= x) & (df['max'] >= x)]) - 1)
```

Output:

|  | eqmt_id | brand_no | ndt | min | max | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | BH40 122 | 2021-03-28 05:10:00 | 2021-03-28 05:30:00 | 2021-04-06 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | BH40 200 | 2021-04-25 20:31:00 | 2021-04-25 21:00:00 | 2021-05-03 18:30:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | BH40 541 | 2020-09-13 11:33:00 | 2020-09-13 12:00:00 | 2020-09-23 12:30:00 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | BH40 619 | 2020-11-08 22:53:00 | 2020-11-08 23:00:00 | 2020-11-18 10:30:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | BH40 649 | 2020-12-02 04:46:00 | 2020-11-17 05:00:00 | 2020-12-09 18:00:00 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Do this, this will faster than common loop.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# following two lines generate two (df.shape[0], df.shape[0]) matrix.
# first matrix min_judge[i][j] means if i 'max' larger than j 'min'
min_judge = df["max"].astype(int).values >= df["min"].astype(int).values.reshape(-1, 1)
# second matrix max_judge[i][j] means if i 'max' smaller than j 'max'
max_judge = df["max"].astype(int).values <= df["max"].astype(int).values.reshape(-1, 1)
# result should minus 1(line itself)
result_column_values = np.array(min_judge & max_judge).sum(axis=0) - 1
# assign values
df.loc[:, "counter"] = result_column_values
print(df)
```

this will get

```
  eqmt_id  brand_no  ...                 max counter
0        1  BH40 122  ... 2021-04-06 08:00:00       0
1        1  BH40 200  ... 2021-05-03 18:30:00       0
2        1  BH40 541  ... 2020-09-23 12:30:00       0
3        2  BH40 619  ... 2020-11-18 10:30:00       1
4        2  BH40 649  ... 2020-12-09 18:00:00       0
```